# Calendar events not fetching | Microsoft Graph API | Using premium personal outlook accounts

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to fetch the calendar events from my **personal premium outlook account**. It is **not a work account.** 
I have a office 365 subscription. Using the same, I have setup Azure actuve directory where I have added my python web application, granted all the required permissions  to the app. While accessing the API via web app I am able to fetch profile details, users and all, but unable to get data related to events, calendar etc. 
**I am getting this error** - "message": "The tenant for tenant guid \u00*******b5d-***9-4b**-b**1-c**5c***2ec8\u0027 does not exist."

I looked at many solutions on msdn and also on stackoverflow, but everyone told to get a premium account which I did but still the issue is not resolved.

Please help resolving the same. Thankyou in advance :)

I am attaching the copy of my **app.config** file for your reference.

```
import os

CLIENT_SECRET = "client secret key" 

AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id"

CLIENT_ID = "client id"

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"    

ENDPOINT =ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my id}/events
# I also tried 'ENDPOINT = ' 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my id}/calendar/events''

SCOPE = ["User.ReadBasic.All"]

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # So token cache will be stored in server-side session
```

Comment: Is the O365 subscription in the Azure AD tenant identified by `tenant id` in your script?

Comment: Yes it's same, my O365 and azure AD account and tenant id is same. My account is like 'test@outlook.com' (just a sample id) and I have subscribed 0365 and Azure active directory.

Comment: Could you please try to change the "tenant id" to "common" ?

Comment: I did it's throwing a different error. Access is denied due to invalid credentials.\u003c/h2\u003e\r\n  \u003ch3\u003e.You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: so you have business premium account now? there is no such thing as a personal premium account.

Comment: @Ayush So could you please share a screenshot of the permissions which you have added to the app ?

Comment: hey I got it solved. Thankyou @HuryShen for helping. Actually I had to pass the token hving the user identity associated with it which I was not passing initially. Thankyou again

Comment: @Ayush Since you have solved the problem, could you please provide the solution at the "answer" area. This can be beneficial to others.

Comment: @HuryShen yes i'll put it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'Oauth' class of python to pass all your token and ADD details like client id, client secret etc.
Something like this - 
(Note config files contains all my details mentioned above.)

```
OAUTH = OAuth(APP)
MSGRAPH = OAUTH.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key=config.CLIENT_ID,
    consumer_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': config.SCOPES},
    base_url=config.RESOURCE + config.API_VERSION + '/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    authorize_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.AUTH_ENDPOINT)
```

my config file :

```
CLIENT_ID = 'put here'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'put here'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/login/authorized'

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'

AUTH_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
SCOPES = ['User.Read', 'Mail.Send', 'Files.ReadWrite','Calendars.Read', 'Calendars.ReadWrite']
```

now you can call the get events like this :

```
eventResponse = MSGRAPH.get('me/events',headers=request_headers()) #request_headers() return all the requeried headers
print(eventResponce.data)
```